# Remove unwanted parts from strings in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for an efficient way to remove unwanted parts from strings in a DataFrame column.

My dataframe:

```
     Passengers

1    Sally Muller, President, Mark Smith, Vicepresident, John Doe, Chief of Staff
2    Sally Muller, President, Mark Smith, Vicepresident
3    Sally Muller, President, Mark Smith, Vicepresident, John Doe, Chief of Staff
4    Mark Smith, Vicepresident, John Doe, Chief of Staff, Peter Parker, Special Effects
5    Sally Muller, President, John Doe, Chief of Staff, Peter Parker, Special Effects, Lydia Johnson, Vice Chief of Staff
...
```

desired form of df:

```
     Passengers

1    Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe
2    Sally Muller, Mark Smith
3    Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe
4    Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Parker
5    Sally Muller, John Doe, Peter Parker, Lydia Johnson
...
```

Up to now I did it with endless handmade copy/paste regex list:

```
df = df.replace(r'President,','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Vicepresident,','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Chief of Staff,','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Special Effects,','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Vice Chief of Staff,','', regex=True) 
...
```

Is there a more comfortable way to do this?

**Edit**

More accurate example of original df:

```
     Passengers

1    Sally Muller, President, EL Mark Smith, John Doe, Chief of Staff,  Peter Gordon, Director of Central Command
2    Sally Muller, President, EL Mark Smith, Vicepresident
3    Sally Muller, President, EL Mark Smith, Vicepresident, John Doe, Chief of Staff, Peter Gordon, Dir CC 
4    Mark Smith, Vicepresident, John Doe, Chief of Staff, Peter Parker, Special Effects
5    President Sally Muller, John Doe Chief of Staff, Peter Parker, Special Effects, Lydia Johnson , Vice Chief of Staff
...
```

desired form of df:

```
     Passengers

1    Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Gordon
2    Sally Muller, Mark Smith
3    Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Gordon
4    Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Parker
5    Sally Muller, John Doe, Peter Parker, Lydia Johnson
...
```

Up to now I did it with endless handmade copy/paste regex list:

```
df = df.replace(r'President','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Director of Central Command,','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Dir CC','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Vicepresident','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Chief of Staff','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Special Effects','', regex=True) 
df = df.replace(r'Vice Chief of Staff','', regex=True) 
...
```

messy output is like:

```
     Passengers

1    Sally Muller, , Mark Smith, John Doe, , Peter Gordon,
2    Sally Muller, Mark Smith,
3    Sally Muller, Mark Smith,, John Doe, Peter Gordon
4    Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Parker
5    Sally Muller,, John Doe, Peter Parker , Lydia Johnson,
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every passenger has their title, then you can use `str.split` + `explode`, then select every second item starting from the first item, then `groupby` the index and `join` back:

```
out = df['Passengers'].str.split(',').explode()[::2].groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

or `str.split` + `explode` and apply a lambda that does the selection + `join`

```
out = df['Passengers'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::2]))
```

Output:

```
0                 Sally Muller,  Mark Smith,  John Doe
1                            Sally Muller,  Mark Smith
2                 Sally Muller,  Mark Smith,  John Doe
3                 Mark Smith,  John Doe,  Peter Parker
4    Sally Muller,  John Doe,  Peter Parker,  Lydia...
```

**Edit:**

If not everyone has a title, then you can create a set of titles and split and filter out the titles. If the order of the names don't matter in each row, then you can use set difference and cast each set to a list in a list comprehension:

```
titles = {'President', 'Vicepresident', 'Chief of Staff', 'Special Effects', 'Vice Chief of Staff'}

out = pd.Series([list(set(x.split(', ')) - titles) for x in df['Passengers']])
```

If order matters, then you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
out = pd.Series([[i for i in x.split(', ') if i not in titles] for x in df['Passengers']])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is still a little issue: Not all of the passengers actually have a title. So unfortunately 'explode' is not working.

Comment: @MountQ see the edit. see if it works now

Comment: Sorry, does not work. I get only a messy list comprehension. Seems like there are commata where there shouldn't be - and vice versa. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: @MountQ I don't understand what you're saying. Could you show a sample output that shows that it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I try it with an edit, see above. The Problem is the messy original data.

Answer (score 1):

This is one case where `apply` is actually faster that `explode`:

```
df2 = df['Passengers'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split(', ')[::2])) #.to_frame() # if dataframe needed
```

output:

```
                                          Passengers
0                 Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe
1                           Sally Muller, Mark Smith
2                 Sally Muller, Mark Smith, John Doe
3                 Mark Smith, John Doe, Peter Parker
4  Sally Muller, John Doe, Peter Parker, Lydia Jo...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is still a little issue: Not all of the passengers actually have a title. So unfortunately 'apply' is not working.

Comment: @MountQ then the issue is not due to `apply` but to the general logic of taking every other value. You need to define which titles exist, then I can modify the filter

Answer (score 0):

We can create a [full regex pattern match](https://regex101.com/r/oMrXB3/1) on every string you need to remove and replace.

This can handle situations were the passengers will not have a title.

```
df2 = df['Passengers'].str.replace("(President)|(Vicepresident)|(Chief of Staff)|(Special Effects)|(Vice Chief of Staff)", "",regex=True).replace("( ,)", "", regex=True).str.strip().str.rstrip(",")
```